# When does Tracker url in the Torrent file come in the action?

Tags: download, bittorrent, p2p

i read few articles but i dont understand 
how  does Tracker url in the Torrent file works ? i mean 
When does Tracker url in the Torrent file come in the action?

Lets say , i created a torrent file and while creating it, i only added tracker1 url

but after i pass the .torrent file to my friend,

he adds the tracker2 url in the torrent client for this specific torrent file,

so my question is when does tracker comes in the picture ?

1 ) As soon as the new tracker url is added and torrent client is downloading content of that torrent file ?
**At the time of Seeding**

or

2 ) User adds the new tracker url and passes the torrent file to another user, then at the time when the new user tries to download file the new tracker comes in the action?

**At the time of Leeching**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tracker(s) are used to get contact-info to other peers (users) that is active on a torrent.
A tracker can only give you info about peers that is registered on that tracker.
A peer is registered on a tracker if it has recently been in contact with it. Normally every 30 mins.

A peer can also get contact-info to other peers by using **DHT** (distributed hash table), **PEX** (peer exchange) or **LPD** (local peer discovery). Usually these methods are de-activated on torrents from private tracker portals.